# Total Commander zip command line

Tags: command-line, zip, total-commander

is there a command line command to use the Total Commander's pack/unpack function?
I know how to use 7Zip and command line but I want to know if there is also a command line for zipping with Total Commander

Answer (score 1):

Yes, actually there's tc command pair: `cm_PackFiles` and `cm_unpackFiles` (which, obviously, works only on tc commandline/box) against selected files on the current panel, try it..

Answer (score 0):

In Total Commander, please navigate to Configuration -> Options -> Misc.

Create a command, for example:

- Name: `em_zip`
- Command: `7z`
- Parameters: `a %N.7z %N`

Now bind it to whatever you like and voila :)

I find this approach to be way more convenient than `cm_PackFiles` as you get no superfluous prompt - you just zip what's under the cursor into `.7z` archive of the same name. I use the same approach for unzipping as well.